# How to add extra numbers in textbox automatically

Tags: java, android-studio

i am trying to make a textbox that has its limit of 32 characters.

If someone enters value like 1234 the program must add 26 Zeros infront example

```
0000...1234
```

I have made the limit for 32 characters in xml

```
android:maxLength="32"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public String appendChars(String string) {

    int expectedSize = 32;
    // 32 zeros string
    String zeros = "00000000000000000000000000000000";
    int inputLength = string.length();

    // append and return
    if (inputLength < expectedSize) {
        string = zeros.substring(0, expectedSize - inputLength) + string;
    }

    return string;

}
```

can do something like this